# Is the inequality $\:\frac{r^2}s +\frac{s^2}r\geqslant 2\max\{r,s\}\:$ a valid one?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality, real-numbers

I'm not sure if
$$\frac 12\left(\frac{r^2}s + \frac{s^2}r\right)\;\geqslant\;
\max\{r,s\}$$
holds true for all $\,r,s\in\mathbb R^{>0}$.

I think so $\,\ddot\smile\:$ but
*Do you have a good proof for it?*

$\ddot\frown\:$ The cyclic analogue in three variables
$$\max \big\{u,v,w\big\} \;\overset{\displaystyle ?}{\leqslant}\;
\frac 13\left(\frac{u^2}v + \frac{v^2}w + \frac{w^2}u\right)$$
certainly/already fails because evaluating the RHS at $\,(u,v,w)=(3,2,1)\,$ yields $\,2\tfrac{17}{18}$.

Comment: Have you tried replacing $max(r,s) = \frac{1}{2}(r+s+|r-s|)$? That would make it more algebraic. Maybe then rearrange and square or something similar to get rid of the modulus.

Comment: This is not true when $$\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}<\frac{s}{r}<1$$ Bt elswhere it is fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that if $\,1<\frac rs<1.618$, then
$$\frac 12\left(\frac{r^2}s + \frac{s^2}r\right)\;\geqslant\;
\max\{r,s\}$$ is not true.
For example put $\,r=1.5 s\,$ so we have 
$$\frac 12\left(\frac{(1.5s)^2}s + \frac{s^2}{1.5s}\right)\;\geqslant\;\max\{1.5s,s\}\\
\frac 12\left(2.25s +.666...s \right)\;\geqslant\;\max\{1.5s,s\}\\
(2.25s +.666...s )\;\geqslant\;2\max\{1.5s,s\}\\[2ex]
2.91666s\;\color{red}\ngeqslant\;3s\\$$

Answer (score 1):

> **Your Claim is False See below:** Indeed, 
>   \begin{split}
> &&\frac 12\left(\frac{r^2}s + \frac{s^2}r\right)\;\geqslant\;
> \max\{r,s\}\\ 
> &\Longleftrightarrow& \frac 12\left(\frac{r^2}s + \frac{s^2}{r}\right) \;\geqslant\; r \quad and \quad\frac 12\left(\frac{r^2}{s} + \frac{s^2}r\right)\;\geqslant\;s \\  &\Longleftrightarrow& \left(\frac{r^2}s + \frac{s^2}{r}\right) \;\geqslant\; 2r \quad and \quad\left(\frac{r^2}{s} + \frac{s^2}r\right)\;\geqslant\;2s \\&  \Longleftrightarrow& \left(\frac{r}s + \frac{s^2}{r^2}\right) -2\;\geqslant\;
> 0 \quad and \quad\left(\frac{r^2}{s^2} + \frac{s}r\right)-2\;\geqslant\;
> 0\\& \Longleftrightarrow &f(t)\ge 0 \quad and \quad f(\frac{1}{t})\ge 0
> \end{split}

Where $t=\frac{s}{r}$ and  $f(t) = t^2 +\frac{1}{t} - 2$ , for $t>0$. Let study $f(t)$ for $t>0$.

We have

$$f'(t) = 2t -\frac{1}{t^2} = 0\Longleftrightarrow t= \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2}}$$

where $$\lim_{t\to 0}f(t)=\lim_{t\to \infty}f(t)=\infty$$

Therefore $f(\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2}})$ is the only minimum of $f$ on $(0,\infty)$ that is,
 $$\forall t>0,~~  f(t) \ge f(\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2}}) = 3*2^{-\frac{2}{3}} -2$$

But $$3*2^{-\frac{2}{3}} -2<0 $$

therefore there exists $0<a<1$ such that $f(a) = f(1) = 0$  and $f(t)< 0$ for $t\in(a,1)$ in particular 
$$f(\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2}}) = 3*2^{-\frac{2}{3}} -2<0.$$ 
Moreover, we have, $$a=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\qquad \text{that is,}\qquad f( \frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}) = f(1)=0 $$

and $$f(t)< 0 \qquad \text{for}\qquad \frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}<t<1.$$
**Hence your claim is FALSE**

Comment: The equivalence in your very first line is not clear to me: How do you relate $\max\{1,{s\over r}\}$ to $1$? And in the sequel: Should one understand $3.2$ as $3\cdot 2$? If so, then pls use \cdot instead of the decimal point.

Comment: Ok See that $\max\{a,b\} < M$ iff $a<M$ and $b<M$ do you agree with this. this what I use there

Comment: What is unclear ? replace in each case $\max(r,s)$ by $r$ and  $s$ respectively. then make some cancellation from both side. Ex $$\frac 12\left(\frac{r^2}s + \frac{s^2}r\right)\;\geqslant\;
\max\{r,s\} \Longleftrightarrow \left(\frac{r^2}s + \frac{s^2}{r}\right) \;\geqslant\;
2r \qquad and \qquad\left(\frac{r^2}{s} + \frac{s^2}r\right)\;\geqslant\;2s
$$ I hope this step is clear for you now?

Comment: And also with additional assumption do you want to use since $r,s>0$ I think this enough . No additional assumption was made

Comment: Aahh, got it. _T h a n k s  for stopping my blindness!_

Comment: I edited for you

Comment: And I edited for you, but declined ... nevertheless: Adapting the size of the parentheses & replacing the asterisks $\,*\,$ with multiplication points (\cdot) would improve readability. Summa summarum your answer is useful (+1).